# PCIe add-in card thickness tolerance

Tags: pcie, tolerance, stack-up

I can't find a tolerance measurement for the 62 mils thickness specified in the PCIe electromechanical spec. How much leeway do I have for board thickness in an add-in card.

Additional details: I'm trying to build a composite video (75 ohm single ended) PCIe add in card. For a 4 layer board, my fab house doesn't have a standard size core that would bring the stack up to exactly 62 mils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test specifications for [at least one connector](http://portal.fciconnect.com/Comergent/fci/documentation/gs-12-584.pdf) (items 3.1.5 and 3.1.6) suggest that the range of allowable thickness would be 1.44 to 1.70 mm (0.057 to 0.069 inches), which would be a tolerance of about ±8%.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to go with my fab's default tolerance of +-0.007". I was told IPC standards are +-0.010" which is too far out of tolerance.